# UITableView load a Custom Cell from NIB file throws NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nib

In an ios application I have a UITableView. In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I need to return a custom cell using it's NIB name. For that I use `loadNibNamed`. (I will fill the data in the cell after the load in the 'willDisplayCellforRowAtIndexPath')

MyItemCell is a XIB file (MyItemCell.xib) that containg 2 UIImageView and a UIButton (Each item has a tag)

This is my code:

In my viewController

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [ViewHelper loadCustomCellWithNibName:@"MyItemCell" owner:self];
}
```

And the method to load the Custom cell from NIB

```
+ (UITableViewCell *) loadCustomCellFromNib:(NSString *)nibName owner:(id)owner
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:owner options:nil];
    if([nibObjects count] > 0 )
    {
        cell = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load %@ XIB file!", nibName);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Everything works correctly in all the testings. However I received a crash from some users that I was unable to reproduce.

This is the crash:

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException

Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/7A24cE79-131F-523F-4C00-23B523ARG123/MyApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'MyItemCell'
```

The stack trace:

```
0 CoreFoundation                        0x39b432a3 __exceptionPreprocess + 163 + 162

1 libobjc.A.dylib                       0x33a3297f objc_exception_throw + 31 + 30

2 CoreFoundation                        0x39b431c5 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 1

3 UIKit                                 0x32e12491 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1637 + 1636

4 UIKit                                 0x32e1a1d7 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 139 + 138

5 MyApp                                 0x00047ded +[ViewHelper loadCustomCellFromNib:owner:] (ViewHelper.m:349)

6 MyApp                                 0x00034003 -[BuildViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (BuildViewController.m:2432)

7 UIKit                                 0x32cc0545 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 413 + 412

8 UIKit                                 0x32ca530b -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1311 + 1310

9 UIKit                                 0x32cbc7c7 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 207 + 206

10 UIKit                                0x32c78803 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 259 + 258
```

The problem is that I was not able to reproduce this crash.

Any idea on what might have caused the crash? Or any solutions to avoid such an error?

Thanks a lot for any help

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify more, This is working perfectly fine on any testing that I'm doing. This crash appeared only 1 time for 1 user so the problem is not with the code. I am just searching for reasons that might cause this crash in a very specific scenario. Thanks

Comment: The important thing to remember is that nibname and cell identifier are different. Name is in the identity inspector, the identifier is in the attributes inspector

Answer (score 12):

To create custom cell from NIB file try this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:CellIdentifier bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    ......
    return cell;
}
```

CellIdentifier is a name of NIB file, used also as cell identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this...It will not give any problem...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"albumListCell";
   albumListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil)
   {
         cell = (albumListCell *) [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"albumListCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
   }
   return cell;
}
```

Creating tableViewCell with nib file is not possible..So create a simple View controller,and then change UIViewController to UITableViewCell...